# What does "No visible @interface for 'App Delegate'..." mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3dtouch

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "SetupViewController.h"

#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

#import "NSObject+Utils.h"
#import "WebProjectSetupHelper.h"
#import "WebProjectSetupHelperDelegate.h"
#import "LoadingView.h"

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "NSObject+Utils.h"

#import "DeviceModelInfo.h"
#import "UIDevice+System.h"
#import "Alert.h"

@interface AppDelegate () <WebProjectSetupHelperDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, strong) WebProjectSetupHelper *helper;
@property (nonatomic, strong) LoadingView *loadingView;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [self createItemsWithIcons];

    // determine whether we've launched from a shortcut item or not
    UIApplicationShortcutItem *item = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey];
    if (item) {
        NSLog(@"We've launched from shortcut item: %@", item.localizedTitle);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"We've launched properly.");
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I am using this code in my App Delegate but on the line that contains "[self createItemsWithIcons];", I get an error that says "No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'createItemsWithIcons'".

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am trying to add quick actions with 3D touch to my app.

---

**Update!** I got that issue resolved. Now my next question is from my AppDelegate, how can I run code that is in different file? In the "www" folder there is a file that ends in .js. In that file, there is javascript code that I want to run. Any Ideas on how to call that file?

Comment: Where is the `createItemsWithIcons` method?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to add implementation for `createItemsWithIcons` method.

https://github.com/versluis/3D-Touch/blob/master/3D%20Touch/AppDelegate.m

If you are working with 3D-Touch sample, then add this code to AppDelegate:

```
- (void)createItemsWithIcons {

    // create some system icons (doesn't work)
//    UIApplicationShortcutIcon *loveIcon = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithType:UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeLove];
//    UIApplicationShortcutIcon *mailIcon = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithType:UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeMail];
//    UIApplicationShortcutIcon *prohibitIcon = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithType:UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeProhibit];

    // icons with my own images
    UIApplicationShortcutIcon *icon1 = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:@"iCon1"];
    UIApplicationShortcutIcon *icon2 = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:@"iCon2"];
    UIApplicationShortcutIcon *icon3 = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:@"iCon3"];

    // create several (dynamic) shortcut items
    UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem *item1 = [[UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem alloc]initWithType:@"com.test.dynamic" localizedTitle:@"Dynamic Shortcut" localizedSubtitle:@"available after first launch" icon:icon1 userInfo:nil];
    UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem *item2 = [[UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem alloc]initWithType:@"com.test.deep1" localizedTitle:@"Deep Link 1" localizedSubtitle:@"Launch Nav Controller" icon:icon2 userInfo:nil];
    UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem *item3 = [[UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem alloc]initWithType:@"com.test.deep2" localizedTitle:@"Deep Link 2" localizedSubtitle:@"Launch 2nd Level" icon:icon3 userInfo:nil];

    // add all items to an array
    NSArray *items = @[item1, item2, item3];

    // add this array to the potentially existing static UIApplicationShortcutItems
    NSArray *existingItems = [UIApplication sharedApplication].shortcutItems;
    NSArray *updatedItems = [existingItems arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:items];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].shortcutItems = updatedItems;

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but how should I do that?

Comment: Copy and paste code snippet inside AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: Thank you for a response. After doing that, more issues came up. I am not using my own images and do not have any dynamic buttons, only static. So really all I would need is the last group of code and the first line right? Commenting out everything else causes an error is the second line of the last group of code.

Comment: No, it is not enough for you, because `items` depends on `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, which depends on image icons. Try to find 3 small icons, replace with them icons from the code snippet, build and run you app to see what happens and how it can be improved for your needs.